# editing and sorting references

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have a project split into several `tex` files that I make through `Sweave` (an R function that weaves together LaTeX and R code). One of the files contains lines for references:

```
\section{Viri in reference}
\def\section*#1{}
\bibliographystyle{/media/spajza1/tex/styles/diploma2}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{/media/spajza1/clanki/bazaclankov}
```

I create the pdf in the following manner.

```
pdflatex diploma; bibtex diploma; pdflatex diploma; pdflatex diploma
```

`diploma.tex` contains links to other segments of the project through `\include`. One of them is the above mentioned file with code for references.

Because I have a few references starting with local characters, the order is not as I would want it to be. Where (or when in the sequence of producing a pdf) can I change the order of references (and perhaps edit them a bit)? I use JabRef as a reference manager.

*EDIT*
I will add these few lines for posterity if I need to come back later to see how I resolved this.

```
@TECHREPORT{Stirn1981,
  author = "{\noopsort{Stirn} Štirn, J.}",
  title = {Manual of methods in aquatic environmental research},
  institution = {Food and agriculture organization of the united nations},
  year = {1981},
  timestamp = {2010.09.05}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[See the Tex FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-bibprefixsort), which provides a horrible workaround for just this issue.

Comment: Your suggestion fits my problem like daddy on mommy. It did take me a while to get the syntax correctly.